# Reorder boxes in JQuery Masonry

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-masonry

I am trying to re-order/sort at random the boxes displayed by [JQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html) on a page, on a button press/function call.

The `append button` [on this demo page](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html) reorders the items after adding a new one.

Is there a function available to do this?

Comment: I'd also really like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `reloadItems` method described in the docs [here](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html)

```
 .masonry( 'reloadItems' )
```